# dynamic templateUrl in directive based on element attribute interpolation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an html element that looks like the following:

```
<new-element data-type="{{widget.type}}"></new-element>
```

I would like to have my directive use a different `templateUrl` depending on what the `type` is.

```
appDirectives.directive('newElement', function() {          
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope: false,               
        templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {      
            var template_url = (attrs.type == 'widgetA') ? 'template-a.html' : 'template-other.html';
            return template_url;
        }
    }
});
```

The template that always get returned is `template-other.html` because the `type` value was still `{{widget.type}}` and has not been interpolated yet.

Is there some way to put a watch on the `type` attribute and have the template change accordingly?

Comment: maybe you can use `routeProvider` in angularJs. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that:

```
var template_url = (attrs.type == 'widgetA') ? 'template-a.html' : 'template-other.html';
```

because you haven't access to directive properties in your template method, but you can do something like this:

```
appDirectives.directive('newElement', function() {          
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
         type: '='
        },
        controller: 'SomeController',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        template: '<div ng-if="ctrl.type === 'widgetA'"><!-- your widgetA contet --></div><div ng-if="ctrl.type === 'widgetB'"><!-- your widgetB content --></div>';
    }
});
```

Here you can find an article on how to do what you want with link function, but i suggest to use a controller instead.

http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/